# Jetty error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: scala, servlets, http4s, xsbt-web-plugin

I am using [HTTP4S](https://http4s.org/) and the webapp is running on jetty. The web app file is configured as:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">


   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>user-svc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>io.databaker.UserSvcServlet</servlet-class>
      <async-supported>true</async-supported>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>user-svc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The available URI's are:

```
object UserSvcRoutes {

  def helloWorldRoutes[F[_]: Sync](H: HelloWorld[F]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F]{}
    import dsl._
    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root =>
        Ok("Example")
      case GET -> Root / "hello" / name =>
        for {
          greeting <- H.hello(HelloWorld.Name(name))
          resp <- Ok(greeting)
        } yield resp
    }
  }

}
```

When I call http://localhost:8080/ I've got:

[image]
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Http4sServlet`](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/v0.21.4/servlet/src/main/scala/org/http4s/servlet/Http4sServlet.scala) was recently made abstract, with two concrete implementations provided by [`BlockingHttp4sServlet`](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/v0.21.4/servlet/src/main/scala/org/http4s/servlet/BlockingHttp4sServlet.scala) and [`AsyncHttp4sServlet`](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/v0.21.4/servlet/src/main/scala/org/http4s/servlet/AsyncHttp4sServlet.scala).

You can get your example working by changing `UserSvcServlet` to extend either of these:

```scala
package io.databaker

import AppContextShift._
import cats.effect._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import org.http4s.server.DefaultServiceErrorHandler
import org.http4s.servlet.BlockingHttp4sServlet
import org.http4s.servlet.BlockingServletIo

class UserSvcServlet
  extends BlockingHttp4sServlet[IO](
    service = UserSvcServer.start,
    servletIo = BlockingServletIo(4096, Blocker.liftExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())),
    serviceErrorHandler = DefaultServiceErrorHandler
  )
```